# How to show Gift Message on Order Invoice Pdf Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, invoice-pdf, giftmessage

> I am trying to display Gift Message on Order Invoice Pdf if order
>   customers are applying Gift Message While placing order Magento 2. If
>   anyone have idea please guide me.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: Here this code worked for Link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292286/how-to-get-gift-message-data-on-invoice-pdf-in-backend-sales-order-grid-magento/292395#292395